# HTML - How to change button background color on OnClick event

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have following PHP code where 4 buttons are displaying dynamically from database table. Different content is displaying on page based on clicked button.

Now, I want to do so when I click 1st button then button bg color should be changed so visitor can know which button is pressed. When 2nd button is clicked then bg color of that button should be changed and previously clicked button (1st button in this example) should be restored with original color.

Please let me know easiest way to do this using either CSS or Javascript.

```
<form name="frm_list" action="toptipper.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<?php 
while(!$rs_tab_list->eof())
{
?>

<button type="submit" name="btn_tab" value="<?php print($rs_tab_list->fields("tabpkid")); ?>"><?php print($rs_tab_list->fields("title")); ?></button>

<?php  
$rs_tab_list->movenext();
}       
?>

</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uncomment out the comment marks if you want only one selected at a time.

```js
$('button').on("click",function(){  
  //$('button').not(this).removeClass();
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  
  });
```

```css
.active{background-color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for response, your code is working fine here. http://jsfiddle.net/hjLn7dym/ ... 

But for some reason, it's not working on page. What may be possible issue? Please help.

Comment: have you got jquery included ? i'll do a quick plain js version, give me a mo.

Comment: Yes, I included jquery file as you mentioned in your example.

Comment: won't bother with the plain js. Can't really understand what is happening. Check that all code is copied, ie,check semicolons etc. have a look in the console for any clues. I have to go out now but back in a while and we'll sort it out.

Comment: Got the problem. JS code should be written after HTML button code. Also this code works fine but my page is refreshed whenever button is clicked so i needed to do some programming related things to get required result. Thank you for your all help.

Answer (score 2):

Write JS `Onclick` event like this `onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';"`

```
<?php 
while(!$rs_tab_list->eof())
{
?>

<button type="submit" name="btn_tab"  onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';" value="<?php print($rs_tab_list->fields("tabpkid")); ?>"><?php print($rs_tab_list->fields("title")); ?></button>

<?php  
$rs_tab_list->movenext();
}       
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Red color is removed once button is clicked, I want it to be there until I press other button. Please let me know what change I need to do in code to work as per requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if changing the button color like this is the best design decision, but just in case it's purely for learning purposes:

1) give the 2 buttons different IDs

2) use this javascript code

```
b1.onclick = function() {
     b1.style.background = "green";
     b2.style.background = "";   }

b2.onclick = function() {
     b1.style.background = "";
     b2.style.background = "green";  }
```

Live example:

[JS Fiddle - click the buttons and see how the colors change](http://jsfiddle.net/gypv7e3g/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('button').on("click",function(){  
  //$('button').not(this).removeClass();
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  
  });
```

```css
.active{background-color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

add id to button and then something like:

```
$('#buttonID').css('background-color','coloryouwant');
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to restore the intial value of the previous button, an easy way to do this is with jQuery. You can use the addClass() routine for this. For example:

```
//Restore all values
$("input").removeClass();
$("input").addClass("default");

//Set class that has the highlight color
$("#button2").addClass("highlight");
```

With this HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="button1"/>
<input type="button" id="button2"/>
```

And this CSS:

```
.default { background-color: blue;}
.highlight { background-color: yellow;}
```

Just add the onClick to the element to call the right functions.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty direct with jquery. I advice to add class using jquery and style the button later. Below fiddle helps you.

http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvarthi/oudkau4j/

```
$("button").click(function(){ 
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use js. Create class `.active` and define it in your css:

```
.active {
    background-color: #yourcolor;
}
```

Now using js jquery you can make onclick event and add class on clicked button:

```
$('#yourbtnid').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
}
```

!Don't forget to import jquery library before your js file or code in html file

Answer (score 0):

in the button you can call a jquery function like

```
<input type="button" onClick=colorchange();>
```

/* in the jquery function you can do.*/

```
function colorchange(){
$(this).css('background-color','#000000');
}
```